# semi-circle button android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button

I have two buttons and I want to change the shape of them to be semi-circles. Then place them beside each other to make a full circle. An  image has been attached to show how I want the buttons to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Semi-Circle Buttons]

Comment: you should use an image for each button. It's much easier.

Comment: Do you want to add any visual feedbacks on button click too?

Answer (score 5):

You have to create one drawable xml file.

left_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <corners android:radius="1dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="25dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>  // here you have to put dimen as per reqiurement

    <solid android:color="@color/green" />
</shape>
```

right_corner.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <corners android:radius="1dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="25dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
      android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="25dp"/>  // here you have to put dimen as per reqiurement

        <solid android:color="@color/green" />
    </shape>
```

layout.xml

```
<Linearlayout
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <Button android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
             android:background="@draable/left_corner"/>

     <Button android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
             android:background="@draable/right_corner"/>
</Linearlayout>
```

This was work for me..

Answer (score 3):

Try this way it work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"        >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btns"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#f0f0f0"
            />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bbb"

        android:text="B"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

btns.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="30dp"
        android:width="30dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

bbb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="30dp"
        android:width="30dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**#.** First, create two custom `shape` drawable for left and right `half-circle`.

**left_half_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="1000dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="1000dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
</shape>
```

**right_half_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="1000dp"
        android:topRightRadius="1000dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
</shape>
```

**USE:**

**1.** Create a horizontal `LinearLayout` and add two `Button` inside it. Use attribute `layout_weight` to `Buttons` for equal width.

**2.** Set `left_half_circle` as a background of `button_left` and set `right_half_circle` as a background of `button_right`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RED"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/left_half_circle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="GREEN"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/right_half_circle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: How can i use it with image view ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi user23423534,
              Applying xml shape as background to button and placing button side by side will help u solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.

Layout file:

```xml
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

shape drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

shape1 drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
        android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: For each suggestion above I get a layout fidelity warning, is that a problem ?